# What are the e-learning platform opensource actually available?

Tags: open-source, platform

I'm looking for a good elearning platform opensource, can you point me out something? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for elearning opensource framework for web than there is https://moodle.org/.

Comment: You could choose Chamilo, eFront..There are couple of [other open source LMS](http://www.findbestopensource.com/tagged/learning-management) available.